# regex capture multi character delimiter

Tags: c#, regex, match, special-characters

I'm trying to learn regex, but still have no clue. I have this line of code, which successfully seperates the placeholder 'FirstWord' by the '{' delimiter from all following text:

```
var regexp = new Regex(@"(?<FirstWord>.*?)\{(?<TextBetweenCurlyBrackets>.*?)\}");
```

Which reads this string with no problem:

> Greetings{Hello World}

What I want to do is to replace the '{' with a character chain like for instance '/>>'
so I tried this:

```
var regexp = new Regex(@"(?<FirstWord>.*?)\/>>(?<OtherText>.*?)\");
```

I removed the last bracket and replaced the first one with '/>>' But it throws an ArgumentException. How would the correct character combination look like?

Comment: Believe it or not there is actually an unbalance escape in your regex `(?<FirstWord>.*?)/>>(?<OtherText>.*?)\  <-- Unbalanced  '\'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/` does not need to be escaped, unless you use it as the pattern-delimiter.:

```
    @"(?<FirstWord>.*?)/>>(?<OtherText>.*?)\"
```

Also your last `\` will basically escape the `"` which should end the String (c#-wise: remove it):

```
    @"(?<FirstWord>.*?)/>>(?<OtherText>.*?)"
```

And since you want most likely fetch until the END of the String (`.*?` will fetch as less characters as required to satisfy the expression), you should use the `$` at the end or use any other sort of delimiter (whitspace, linebreak, etc...).

```
    @"(?<FirstWord>.*?)/>>(?<OtherText>.*?)$"
```

Example:

```
(.*?)/>>(.*?)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/z3ywT282hN6gQwTr)

Removing the trailing `$` will fetch the empty string for the second match group, because `""` is the shortest string possible satisfying the expression `.*?`

`(.*?)/>>(.*?)$` on `This/>>Test One` will match `This` and `Test One`

`(.*?)/>>(.*?)\s` on `This/>>Test One` will match `This` and `Test`

`(.*?)/>>(.*?)` on `This/>>Test One` will match `This` and `""`

**Note:** I'm saying *"" is the shortest string possible satisfying the expression .*?* on purpose! A frequent Misstake is to interpret `.*?a` as "everything until a":

- Regex is greedy by default!
- Searching for the expressiong `(.*?)a$` on "caba" will **NOT** *fail to match* - it will return `cab`!, because `cab` followed by `a` is satisfying the expression AND `cab` is the shortest string possible for *any* match.
- One might also expect `b` to be matched - but regex is working from left to right, hence aborting once it found `cab` - even if `b` would be shorter.

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and the insight that there are things like Debuggex in the internet. Excellent answer!